# Loading DLL in wxPython

Tags: python, dll, wxpython, ctypes

I am currently loading a cdecl dll in a wxPython application.

The error I am receiving is:

> WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x...

That error arises from running the last line of this code:

```
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("somedll.dll")
some_ctype = ctype_struct()
dll.some_func(ctypes.byref(some_ctype))
```

The weird thing about this is that the code will run happily while it is not running in a wxPython application, or if i add `print []` before the dll function call. I narrowed the print statement requirements to get this thing to work to just having to print some list or tuple...

I can only get this call working if i run it from directly in a file that is then imported in numerous places around my app.

Is someone familiar with wxPython that may understand why this error is occuring?

I am running Python 2.7.3 with 2.8.12.1 wxPython

Thanks

**Edit:**
Apparently it has been working about a quarter of the time... The other three quarters gives me the access violation error.

Comment: I don't know about wxPython. ctypes sets up an SEH handler to catch certain Windows exceptions during a function pointer call, such as `some_func`, which it routes to a `WindowsError`. Otherwise an access violation would terminate the process.

Comment: Hmm Okay. I narrowed it down to specifically a wxPython issue since the only time I am capable of running that code is within a file that is imported in my wxPython application. I might ask it in the wxPython mailing list. It is so incredibly odd... So technically I am never able to run this code during a wxPython application since all imports are evaluated before starting the application.

Comment: If it helps at all, the code runs if it is all static within the class that uses it, so it is only ever ran once... That has to be the issue.

Comment: @eryksun You can't be serious. That was the issue. I am assuming that the difference between ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() and ctypes.CDLL() is that one attempts to load the library each time while the other always checks to see if it has been loaded already before attempting to load it? I will be closing this.

So when would it be appropriate to ever use LoadLibrary as opposed to CDLL unless you wanted a violation of memory to occur when you try to load the dll more than once?

Comment: That is true... Could FreeLibrary potentially be called during cleanup? If that is the case, then this might be the issue.

Comment: The handle returned by Win32 [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175) is set as the `_handle` attribute of the `CDLL` instance. ctypes never calls [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152) on the handle. The DLL stays loaded until the process exits. You can experiment with unloading via `_ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was fixed by calling `ctypes.CDLL("somedll.dll")` as opposed to `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("somedll.dll")`. I am still not 100% positive why calling either of these functions multiple times causes different effects, but I am assuming `LoadLibrary` only attempts to load the library again and if it cannot it will have unwanted side-effects. `CDLL` on the other hand will check if the DLL has already been loaded into memory and use that reference if it can, else it loads the library.